# auctex beamer, set all characters to a fixed size

Tags: auctex, fonts

I am starting to use emacs guy (precisely this https://emacsformacosx.com) and I am not always getting monospaced charters as I get in emacs when using terminal. I have tried putting this in my .emacs (found in the web)

```
;; Only change sectioning colour
(setq font-latex-fontify-sectioning 1.0)
(setq font-latex-fontify-sectioning 'color)
(setq font-latex-slide-title-face 1.0)
;; super-/sub-script on baseline
(setq font-latex-script-display (quote (nil)))
;; Do not change super-/sub-script font
;; Exclude bold/italic from keywords
(setq font-latex-deactivated-keyword-classes
'("italic-command" "bold-command" "italic-declaration" "bold-declaration"))
```

I got some improvements but as you can see in the images I have not solved my problem yet.

What I expect:

[image]

What I get (you can see that "Theoretical introduction" is small and not vertically aligned to other characters). What can I do?
[image]

How to solve it?

Comment: You are using 2 different fonts in the 2nd screen shot (compare `i` in `\begin{figure}` and `Theoretical`).  I suggest you try to find out why this happens.  You can use `C-u C-x =` on those characters to find out which font Emacs is using.

Answer (score 1):

AucTeX modifies provides a bunch of customizable faces. You can view and edit them with `M-x customize-group font-latex-highlighting-faces`. Go through that list, and untick the 'height' box on any that have it set.